# Восстановление данных: (офф)топик или нет?

Tags: обсуждение

Довольно часто появляются вопросы по восстановлению данных, причем вида "Я удалил файлы, что делать?" или "Программа X пишет что файл Y поврежден, чем восстановить и что делать?".

IMHO, такие вопросы - оффтопик, поскольку нет никакой информации о типе повреждения и речь идет о поиске готового софта, а не о написании своего. В то же время, вопросы типа "Как восстановить структуру DIFAT в битом MS-CFB?", я считаю, вполне уместны, поскольку предполагают описание алгоритма восстановления.

В связи с этим вопрос-предложение: а не сделать ли вопрос с информацией по теме, чтобы новые вопросы можно было помечать копиями? Указать название софта для решения подобных проблем и т.д...

Comment: Пример плохого вопроса про восстановление данных: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454987/%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-c-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BB%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454814/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD-dbf-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB - на мой взгляд тоже плохой вопрос: без самого файла - гадание на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу ничего плохого в таких вопросах.

> Я удалил файлы, что делать?

Создать эталонный вопрос со списком соответствующего софта, причём с комментариями, в каких случаях конкретная программа применима и в каких оказывается лучше других. Новые подобные вопросы закрывать как дубликаты.

Кстати, вроде на киберфоруме подобный список был.

> Программа X пишет что файл Y поврежден, чем восстановить и что делать?

А тут вообще вполне можно подсказать другую программу, которая попытается отобразить неповреждённую часть, либо специальную программу для восстановления, если такая есть. В идеале, конечно, увидеть сообщение об ошибке в вопросе, но многие программы его просто не показывают, так что требовать этого в как обязательных данных нельзя.

Если возникают вопросы по тем же программам и типам файлов, то закрывать как дубликаты. Впрочем, это верно для абсолютно любых вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

Восстановление данных - **частично оффтопик**.

"Я удалил файлы, что делать?" - вопрос на который можно дать корректный ответ в зависимости от условий (в свн удалил, в студии, на диске, на флэшке, под никсами и т.п.)

"Программа X пишет что файл Y поврежден, чем восстановить и что делать?" - оффтопик. Каждый вопрос индивидуален и в общем случае не решаем, т.к. данные утеряны. Тут требуется диалог с автором и перебор вариантов. Единого "правильного" решения не будет.